# Padding of Original Message in MD5

Tags: md5

what should I do if my original message is greater than 64 bits? what is the process of padding in MD5?

As described in *Internet Security: Cryptographic Principles, Algorithms and Protocols*, [page 138](http://books.google.com/books?id=rn5QB9_sOJsC&pg=PA138&lpg=PA138&dq=%22a%2064-bit%20representation%20of%20the%20original%20message%20length%22&source=bl&ots=0Mk9QC1Rw0&sig=Y3CSgE8f4XN_rgQ11qVwyJUIz0c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nmuAUYH5DoiGqgHav4H4DQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22a%2064-bit%20representation%20of%20the%20original%20message%20length%22&f=false), the second step in MD5 is to append the length of the message:

[image]

Can someone help me understand exactly what happens when the message length is greater than $2^{64}$ bits?

Comment: you mean greater than $2^{64}$ bits long, right? You realize that that is $2048$ petabytes, right? I'm hoping this isn't a problem you are actually facing. :)

Comment: @mikeazo: you never know when you may need the MD5 digest of exabytes of data!

Comment: Could you please cite your sources? (i.e. From where did you take this image?)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann, I updated with the source.

Answer (score 4):

If the original message length $N$ is $2^{64}$ bits or longer, you encode the value $N \bmod 2^{64}$ in the final padding block, rather than just $N$.  Alternatively, you can just always encode $N \bmod 2^{64}$; if $N < 2^{64}$, then they're the same value.

Now, this distinction between $N$ and $N \bmod 2^{64}$ doesn't happen at 64 bits, it's at $2^{64}= 18,446,744,073,709,551,626$ bits, or about 2000000 Terabytes.  No one has ever hashed a message that long with MD5; even if we assume an MD5 compression function can be computed in 1nsec (massively overoptimistic), it'd take over a year to hash a message that large (and parallelism doesn't help).

Answer (score 4):

I think the [RFC, Section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321#section-3.2) has a little more clear description.

> A 64-bit representation of b (the length of the message before the
> padding bits were added) is appended to the result of the previous
> step. In the unlikely event that b is greater than 2^64, then only
> the low-order 64 bits of b are used. (These bits are appended as two
> 32-bit words and appended low-order word first in accordance with the
> previous conventions.)

So, if the message length is `b2 b1 b0` (where `b2` is the most significant) where each `b` is 32 bits, then `b0 b1` is appended as the message length. In otherwords, if the message is too large, just truncate the **length** (not the message) at 64 bits.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in other answers, the length is taken modulo $2^{64}$ for MD5, but messages longer than $2^{64}$ bits can be safely ignored for any practical purpose.

However, some hash functions use a different solution and forbid you to input a message longer than what can be stored in the counter.  For instance the FIPS 180-4 standard defining SHA-1 states:

> SHA-1 may be used to hash a message, $M$, having a length of $l$ bits, where $0≤l<2^{64}$.